# I'd like to see job ads for part-time or freelance work

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I'm not looking for a full-time job, but if I saw an interesting short-term job that I could finish in a week or maybe a month, I would seriously consider it.

All the ads on Stack Overflow seem to be for full-time, permanent jobs. [I would like to see](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351801/dont-show-job-ads-if-im-not-interested-in-jobs#comment488786_351801) ads for part-time freelance work. [Employers would like to show me ads for part-time freelance work.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321096/job-listings-for-part-time-or-freelance-help) Therefore, I propose that Stack Overflow work something out to bridge the gap. It seems like it could be beneficial for everyone.

Comment: *"All the ads on Stack Overflow seem to be for full-time, permanent jobs."* That's because that's pretty much the only jobs that are listed on the Stack Overflow Jobs site. As far as I know, you are subject to being shown ads according to your preferences; you just won't see any if there aren't any listings to advertise. So the real feature request is getting the SO Jobs team to start soliciting these types of opportunities as well.

Comment: That would indeed be great. I've also been searching for a while, and it's hard to find sensible freelance jobs. The fact that these jobs are far more volatile may make it difficult to handle them under the current "Jobs" umbrella, but it shouldn't be impossible.

Comment: I think this could be hugely beneficial to the software industry.  UpWork is *terrible* and I don't know anywhere else to quickly outsource mid-size ($1k-10k) tasks to.  This would likely require a new product but I can't imagine the dev costs would be too high, especially if payments are handled off-site with a friendly recommendation to pay per-milestone, with tiny milestones required for new participants.  Take my money!

Comment: Great idea, but for clarity don't call it a "job", call it a "Task", "Work" or a "To do" on a dedicated site such as  http://todo.stackexchange.com or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/todo

Comment: @Bohemian huh? your comment doesnt make sense.

Comment: It would be nice to see SO create something that pays, but it is rumored part of the motivation of SO founders was to kill off Experts Exchange, which was for-pay Q&A.  It would be interesting to see the site evolve into a place where expert Q&A is still free, but give-me-the-damn-codez and do-my-whole-project-for-me-as-I-change-the-question-requirements could be diverted into a for-pay site structured to reduce manipulation or provide escrow/referee-ing.  Furthermore, this is a service where SO could collect a fee.  I'd pay if it makes me money.

Comment: I'd love to see something like this, but it would be an entirely new business; it's only tangentially related to the current jobs/careers product. It would also be a constant battle keeping the quality up. All the crappy freelancers you see on upwork would flock to this as well, and so will the customers who are looking for bottom-dollar labor. If anyone could make this model work it'd be SO, but it won't be trivial.

Comment: @tyler "job" in SO has the definition of "full time employment". The topic of is post is "short term employment" (akin to how you hire a tradesman to do .a specific task). We should name the kind of employment using a different word than "job" to make it clear. Actually, "job" was a questionable choice in the first place, because in IT a job is a discrete unit of work (a la a "job queue"), similar to the work this question is about.

Comment: I think working 8 hours a day is not productive especially for a developer. I'm guessing most developers simply cannot focus for that long of a time. In general I think jobs should be less hours with more efficiency. Jobs on stackoverflow should have a searchable part time or freelance designation.

Comment: Try looking through a site like FreeLancer.com, and you'll see the problem with this: too many low-quality offers with unreasonable terms, ethical concerns (i.e. students blatantly trying to get someone else to write his/her thesis for money), legal concerns (requests to help write rootkits effectively), etc. Better off keeping to full-time postings with reputable companies.

Comment: I'm with @DevNull. I really don't want to see SO getting mixed up in the freelancing world.

Comment: @Bohemian Where is that definition given? A job is a both a full-time, ongoing employment thing and also a single task (see "odd job", task scheduler "jobs", "The Italian Job", etc). There's no confusion in letting SO Jobs have both full-time and contract work.

Comment: @NathanArthur I tried using those sites, and it was the same old garbage: $20k for 8 months of work, requests for help with LD_PRELOAD "tools" (i.e. viruses), requests to write entire masters thesis chapters so some criminal can buy a degree from a reputable university. More than half the jobs listed there are actively making the work worse, and pay terrible as well.

Comment: @tyler your last comment *supports* my comment: in general it's not clear what "job" means. However, here at SO it has been used for "full time employment". For **clarity** I suggest a different word be used for freelance tasks. That's all. If you disagree, I don't particularly care. Time will tell us if this even gets off the ground, and if it does what terms will be chosen (including just reusing "job").

Comment: @Bohemian No, it *is* clear what a job is. It's a measurement of units of work. Whether the unit of work is 'ongoing' or a finite number is irrelevant; they're both valid. You want a job? You go to SO Jobs. You want a full-time job or career, filter by that. You want contracts only? Filter by that. Interested in both? Don't set a filter. No ambiguity. It's fine if you don't care that you're wrong, but don't go confusing everyone else with diamond-backed incorrect statements.

Comment: @TylerH You're proposing this feature is added as an option in the existing SO Jobs, yes? I think Bohemian is suggesting a completely separate site section for freelance gigs, and saying that the new section should have a distinct name. (FWIW, I agree with both of you depending on which implementation it would be.)

Comment: Agree. I would participate. I'm cashflow negative in the early stages of a startup, so cannot commit to full time, but would like a smaller engagement. @SB2055 You had me at 'Upwork is terrible.'

Comment: @DevNull just because there are shitty employers (or overeager employees) who don't know how to scope work doesn't mean the SO team should totally ignore an opportunity. This is what policies, reputations, and incremental milestones would address.  After that it's just plain old risk/reward capitalism.  As a new employer I could be forced to scope my work to <$500 milestones that are clearly defined.  Potential takers could provide feedback on the specs until they're clear enough for someone to accept.  It would effectively be StackOverflow on paid steroids - bounties just wouldn't be virtual.

Comment: I can just hear the execs saying that the overhead of managing a million smaller fish for an incremental gain just doesn't make business sense though, which is why there isn't a really successful, trustworthy, go-to marketplace for this kind of work yet.  Only the big fish make business sense so far because of the cost we'd all incur through BS arbitration and liability.

Comment: @SB2055 The two biggest problems I see going that route is: `1)` Crummy postings on freelancer sites are the norm, not the exception. `2)` This starts to create a motivation to withhold contributions to the site, and instead post "pay me for the answer". Kind of like Experts Exchange, but individuals reap the reward instead of the site owners...... Actually, I wouldn't mind that one bit. Someone posts a terrible question normally worth vote-closing, and I demand $500.00 on the spot to solve his/her 11th hour coding problem. SO can keep 10%.

Comment: I'd like to see more contract positions, personally, whether they be full time or part-time.

Comment: @DevNull that was an oversimplification on my part - the last thing I'd want to see is a rebirth of ExpertExchange. A place to post up small-to-midsized contracts within a somewhat self-moderating community (garbage gets flagged) would be great though. I just recently had a need for a self-contained, specialized demo of using `Google Drive`, `Dropbox`, and `OneDrive` as storage providers from within `C#` and it took at least a couple hours of screening to find someone decent on UpWork. I would have preferred to drop $1k on gigs.stackoverflow.com or whatever to get quality work done.

Comment: @SB2055 I almost think it would be neat to have low quality garbage posts (i.e. "Here's a 200 line program. It doesn't work. Why") get migrated to `gigs` and the answer section becomes a contract bidding war. For once, garbage posts could be remotely useful.

Comment: @SB2055 We've created something like this with SourcePanel. We match local, US-based software and IT consultants to short-term projects from vetted customers. There is a shortage of consultants, and I would love to advertise for short-term gigs on StackOverflow.

Comment: @TylerH: He's a wombat, not a snake. I'm not too worried that he is making diamond-backed statements, but fuzzy ones ;)

Comment: I can't speak to changes to our platform, but I can share background about *why* you'll mostly see full-time, permanent jobs. We don't actively pursuing contract jobs (but we do support them). The reason they are a relatively small portion of total jobs might be related to the fact that we typically work with larger companies (rather than small/medium-sized companies).

Comment: @Donna Any short-term plans to change that? According to [the 2017 survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#work) *"10.2% work as independent contractors, freelancers, or are self-employed"*. I'd wager that these people also look for new work more often than those employed full-time. So you're leaving out a non-significant group of people currently.

Answer (score 17):

After reading the comments above and thinking more about this for the last couple days, let me add a more detailed proposal.

### The problem

If Stack Overflow were to add a part-time or freelance jobs/tasks feature, it would need to be much higher quality than the current options on other sites. Specificity, many other sites are bad in the following ways:

- low quality job postings from employers that don't describe in detail what the job entails
- unreasonable requirements: asking too much for too little pay
- requests for help doing unethical or illegal things
- inability of employers to find truly qualified developers

### Four perspectives

Lets look at the needs of the following groups related to this feature request.

Stack Overflow itself

- needs to maintain a quality site
- needs to make money

The general Stack Overflow user

- needs to have free access to browse quality Q&A
- needs to be able to freely get answers to new questions
- needs to be able to increase experience and reputation through answering questions

The developer seeking short-term work

- needs to be able to filter jobs to appropriate tags, pay, and approximate task size
- needs to be able to understand quickly and clearly the scope and requirements of the task
- needs to be paid adequately for work done

The employer seeking developers

- needs to be able to filter applicants to appropriate tags, reputation, and pay
- needs to be able to understand quickly and clearly an applicant's capacity for the task
- Needs advertisement and compensation expenses to be viably low

### Thoughts for implementation

- Stack Overflow should make the advertisement fee sufficiently high to keep out very low quality employers and trivial tasks. However, it should not be so high as to prevent, say, week-long tasks.
- Employers should be required to provide detailed descriptions of the task
- Only specific tasks should be allowed, not some general call for freelancers.
- Large jobs should have very specific milestones that are paid when reached. This would allow both the employer and employee to re-evaluate the other's quality.
- Low quality job postings should be flagable. This could result in employers receiving bans.
- Low quality applicants who spam employers should be flagable. This could result in applicants receiving bans.

Comment: "needs to be able to filter applications to appropriate tags, reputation, and pay" - that's exactly where the problems will start. As soon as you couple reputation and quick cash, Q&A will be swarmed by people trying to rep farm in order to gain an edge on the freelancing board.

Comment: I agree with @NathanArthur. Filtering by reputation shouldn't be allowed by employers. Far too often people relate reputation with knowledge/ability, and while there is certainly some correlation, it is better described as a measure of contribution to the SO community. That said, I don't see how that information could be useful to an employer.

Comment: To further emphasize what @NathanArthur is saying: Allowing employers to filter by reputation would add legitimate value (as in monetary value) to SE accounts. I believe we would begin to see users looking to buy/sell accounts with high rep.

Comment: Marketplaces and reputations go hand-in-hand.  The reputation doesn't have to be related to SE - it could just be a specialized gigs reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that a variant on the [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) system would work well for jobs up to a day or maybe a week.

The employer asks a question stating their requirements, and pays the bounty to StackExchange.

The contractor answers with the solution, or maybe with a description of the solution with a link to code.

If the employer selects an answer, the bounty is awarded.

If not, maybe StackExchange could keep the money, or maybe StackExchange gets a percentage fee and if the employer doesn't award the bounty, it's awarded as bounties normally are when no answer is selected (I forget how that is).

The timeout for awarding the bounty might need to be more than a week.