# Stack Overflow Jobs Update - July 20 2017

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

We have a few updates on [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) we would like to share with you.

#### Job Roles

[Aurélien](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1370722/aur%C3%A9lien-gasser) improved the automatic categorization of jobs by *developer role*.

[image: Developer Role]

We integrated developer roles to job search to help you find more relevant results.

We also introduced new landing pages for easy access to jobs by developer role:

- [Full stack developer jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/full-stack-developer-jobs)
- [Backend developer jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/back-end-developer-jobs)
- [Frontend developer jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/front-end-developer-jobs)
- [Mobile developer jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/mobile-developer-jobs)
- [Data scientist jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/data-scientist-jobs)
- [DevOps jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/devops-jobs)
- [Product manager jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/product-manager-jobs)
- [System administrator jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/system-administrator-jobs)
- [Desktop developer jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/desktop-developer-jobs)
- [Database administrator jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/database-administrator-jobs)
- [Designer jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/designer-jobs)
- [QA/Test developer jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/quality-assurance-developer-jobs)
- [Graphics/Game developer jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/graphics-game-developer-jobs)

---

#### Job listing updates

[Kirti](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1012097/kirti-thorat) updated the listing layout a bit to surface key data points about the job first like role, seniority, technologies, and company info. The new layout also gives you quick links to company culture, more jobs at the company, and the ability to create an alert to get notified when a new job is posted at the company.

[image: New job listing page]

#### Job Collections

[Donna](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4406529/donna) designed and [Gervasio](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/920295/g3rv4) implemented job collections to provide an alternative way to discover jobs. We are running this as a test, so if you’re in the test group, you’ll see these collections.

[image: Collections]

If you're not in the test group, you can still find amazing jobs based on your interests! In the [filter pane](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?ofp=True) we have now the ability to filter by the collection perks:

[image: Collection Perks]

And the "Live and work anywhere" collection can be easily [accessed here](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/live-work-anywhere) (it's just filtering jobs that offer remote, visa sponsorship or relocation).

Feedback is always welcome, so give these a try and let us know!

Comment: I *really* like the landing pages that allow easy sorting by job type. I'm a desktop developer, and I've always been extremely frustrated that the Stack Overflow Jobs site is filled with web programming jobs that I am nearly powerless to filter out. I end up wasting a *bunch* of time going to the listings for individual jobs and immediately dismissing them because, despite having a [c++] tag, they really want someone to do web programming.

Comment: Okay, this might be a dumb question, but…how do we access the landing pages from the [Jobs homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)? They work swell if I click your links here, but I shouldn't have to have those links memorized. There should be some obvious entry point on the main page. I see "Job Collections", as in the screenshot, so I must be in the test group, but I see no way to get to these landing pages.

Comment: @CodyGray on the [filter pane](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?ofp=True) in the "Background" tab, you can filter by role (which is the same filter the landing pages are doing)

Answer (score 7):

I see that there's a "Job Type: **Permanent**" item listed in each example screenshot. Does that mean [I'd like to see job ads for part-time or freelance work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351904/id-like-to-see-job-ads-for-part-time-or-freelance-work) was implemented? It never received a Jobs team response.

Comment: The different job types we currently support are Permanent, Contract and Internship. Effectively supporting part-time or freelance projects would require more than an additional Job Type. Having started my career on RentACoder, I'd love for us to help developers get cool freelance projects and I'm sure we'll get there eventually, but unfortunately it's not on our short-term plans.

Comment: How exactly does "contract" differ from freelance work? Wouldn't you hire a freelancer under a contract?

Comment: @CodyGray It's probably more nuanced; 'contract' workers would probably behave like permanent/full-time workers (e.g. come to work 9 to 5, match dress code, be available to take call if needed, etc.) whereas a freelance contract is just paying for a set number of hours worked (or in some cases perhaps a finished product, depending on the contract terms) and they don't expect you to come in or to be available at any certain hours, just to get the work done and then present at some time.

Comment: Oh, hmm. That makes sense, but it is totally not how I envisioned "contract" jobs. That sounds more like temporary employment. I guess "temp" has a bad connotation nowadays?

Comment: @CodyGray Your guess is as good as mine, there. I am not at all certain my explanation above is how SO would view the differences, it's just how I would differentiate between them if I had to.

Comment: @g3rv4 could you elaborate on that difference?

Comment: @TylerH I've been trying to find an answer for a while now, unsuccessfully. It's a field employers set, so what "Contract" means seems to be based on their understanding of the term. I'm going to continue bothering people until I get a better answer

Answer (score 2):

In what kind of place is only two weeks of vacation considered a "perk" worth searching for? It's pretty much the bare minimum for any FTE in the US, and far below the minimum in Europe. The number should default higher, and customizable by searchers.

Comment: Some such hellholes are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minimum_annual_leave_by_country). While you and many others might consider two weeks to be a "bare minimum" in the United States, the law does not make the same consideration. There are companies that offer no paid vacation whatsoever.