# Why is Stack Overflow Jobs inaccessible to small startups?

Tags: discussion, status-review, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm running a small startup (three technical founders, no employees), focusing on building a single cell genomics platform used by scientists in cancer and heart disease research. We are entirely bootstrapped (we didn't take any angel or seed investment), so we aren't exactly swimming in cash. But recently we've landed a big contract and we are ready to hire (a very much needed) employee #1.

Stack Overflow Jobs seemed like a great place to start searching. So I've eagerly created an account and was booked on a call with a sales rep. Unfortunately, the cheapest plan that we could be offered was 2500 GBP (~3100 USD) – and that's already the "start-up deal". I digged around a bit – small startup founders already complained about the hefty price tag [3 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321096/job-listings-for-part-time-or-freelance-help). But back then you could pay ~400 GBP (495 USD) for a monthly ad (which would actually be good enough value for us). The situation is now 6 times worse, and even in the follow-up discussion, after the sales rep checked with the management, 2500 GBP was the cheapest deal SO Jobs could offer.

This comes as a little bit of a shock to me, speaking as somebody who helped over the years to make SO a better place, initially by asking and recently mostly answering many technical questions. I understand that medium-large tech companies are well capitalised, need the talent just as much as everybody else and can afford to put a lot of resource towards their hiring. For a small startup it's hard enough to scrap up a competitive salary, sweetened by an opportunity to have a large impact working on an important world-changing problem. With such a high financial barrier for the use of SO Jobs, small startups are effectively shut off the platform.

Is this state of affairs good for the community? Are there alternative solutions that would promote diversity of the job ads while still being sustainable for SO business-wise?

Comment: So if you get this sorted, everyone is a small start-up from now on....

Comment: There are ways of verifying this, @Luuklag. Not that it would be *impossible* for people to cheat the system, but...it's also inevitable. I think, on balance, it makes sense to lower the barrier of entry to allow those who would otherwise be excluded.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are these prices much higher than other job boards? I’m wondering if you’re arguing from a place of “the pricing is currently *worse* than other job boards” or “Stack Overflow should have *better* options for start-ups than other companies”. I’ve never done hiring so the numbers don’t mean much to me. All I know about hiring is that it’s expensive.

Comment: @BSMP you can get an ad on indeed.com for 70 USD/week. The candidate quality is usually quite poor though. To be clear, the SO jobs 2500 GBP deal is for 6 months for 1 job slot. You can re-use the job slot as you close off the positions (e.g. you can look for a UX engineer for a month, close the position, and move on to hire a back-end engineer, etc... as long as you have one active job ad at the time). I can see how this works for a large company. In a small startup you only want to fill in one position in 6 months – something I understand you could do in the past for ~400 GBP.

Answer (score 5):

I can see the downside to SO here. Small companies do have a high risk of failure, that is a fact of life. Statistics is a large part of it; you are far more likely to lose 50% of your customers than Google is. And such failures might project on SO jobs. But for only £2500 it would be pretty hard to vet your company.

Of course, there are startups that can balance that risk to employees with a high reward. But the companies that can afford £100.000 for an employee are those who can afford £2500 for the ad.

So the hard problem for SO is that it takes a lot of time to determine which companies should be offered a lower rate, and that means SO initially has higher cost of sales and lower profit on those companies. And that gets us back to the beginning: SO could take a hit on the first advertisement if you would be likely to hire more developers later on, but the fact is that most startups fail and will never place that second ad.

Comment: Thank you @MSalters. I obviously agree that startups have a high failure rate. And it's an interesting point about SO vetting the companies – my understanding is that currently vetting is actually very lightweight and in most circumstances it will be down to the candidate to do due diligence on the company.

Comment: Putting myself in the shoes of a programmer looking at job ads on SO – I think an ad for an employee #1 in a company working on a very new and exciting problem, which comes with a substantial share package would catch my interest much more than an offer to work in a large, established software company. As it stands, these type of ads just don't have a chance to appear on the site, due to a prohibitively expensive deal.

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz: I can see where you're coming from; I'm sort of employee #2.1 on a re-startup. The problem you might be facing is that you're not actually looking for an employee. You're looking for a another founder. Those are notoriously hard to find. "Great business ideas" are rather common, and for a software developer it is reasonable to apply a very crude filter: truly great ideas get funding.

Comment: Thank you for this perspective @MSalters. I didn't quite specify that, but **we are** offering a fair salary in addition to the above listed bonuses. Our position is open to candidates in the Boston area and we are prepared to pay $60k-$90k USD per annum + share package to a capable data visualisation engineer who'd like to join the team!

Comment: I actually really like this idea of approaching employee #1 as somebody in-between a founder and a regular employee. On one hand, they earn a salary, a little less than regular employees 5-10 years down the line. On the other hand, they receive a competitive share package, not as much as the founders, but enough to offset the reduction in pay when compared with working as a regular employee.